# Typescript - store static global variables and retrieve by key?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, typescript2.0

I am trying to do the following. Store variables in a static global file, say with:

```
 declare const MYVAR = 'Some unchanging data';
```

Then later be able to retrieve the information knowing only the key 'MYVAR', i.e.

```
globalFile.findValueByKey('MYVAR');
```

I know typescript doesn't really use reflection - so what is the best way to go about handling this?

Comment: Store them in an object, and retrieve them with `myObject['MYVAR']`

Comment: Sounds like you just need to create a module and export an object from it.

Comment: If you use angular as you tagged here, you can use a service update and expose data object.

Comment: Storing them as an object did the trick - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global provider class and use it where ever you want

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class GlobalProvider {

 public MYVAR:string = 'Some unchanging data';
 constructor() {
 }
```

and you can import it like any other class 
and use

```
import { GlobalProvider } from "providers/global";

someClass{
constructor(private gp: GlobalProvider){
 console.log(gp.MYVAR);
 }

}
```